# What does a slash mean in a Java stack trace?

Tags: java, stack-trace

In the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at burp.ConfigMenu.run(Config.java:38)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

What do the slashes mean? I know what e.g. "burp.ConfigMenu.run(Config.java:38)" means, but not the lines with "java.base" or "java.desktop" in front of it.

It looks like some sort of alias, superclass, namespace... but I can't figure it out. Google/DDG are not very helpful with queries like "slash in java stack trace". I found a few other examples by looking for the classes mentioned, but not what they mean.

Comment: I'd say the part left of the slash tells you which JVM module the class belongs to (as of project Jigsaw)

Comment: @Thomas That could make sense. Searching "jvm module desktop base", I see that [those are indeed modules](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~mr/jigsaw/ea/module-summary.html) as [introduced in Java 9](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/modular-development). It looks like that's it. Do you want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The Javadoc for StackTraceElement toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html#toString--) (Java 9, note) explains the format:

> The first example shows a stack trace element consisting of three
>   elements, each separated by "/" followed with the source file name and
>   the line number of the source line containing the execution point. The
>   first element "com.foo.loader" is the name of the class loader. The
>   second element "foo@9.0" is the module name and version. The third
>   element is the method containing the execution point; "com.foo.Main""
>   is the fully-qualified class name and "run" is the name of the method.
>   "Main.java" is the source file name and "101" is the line number.

Note how some elements of the above are omitted.

> If the class loader is a built-in class loader or is not named then
>   the first element and its following "/" are omitted as shown in
>   "acme@2.1/org.acme.Lib.test(Lib.java:80)". If the first element is
>   omitted and the module is an unnamed module, the second element and
>   its following "/" are also omitted as shown in
>   "MyClass.mash(MyClass.java:9)".

Comment: Woa, that format changed a lot since java 8. Strange that the docs don't mention the only format I've encountered so far, where the second element is omitted and only one slash is shown. Anyway, good to have a reference, thanks for linking the docs!

Comment: It came as a surprise to me too. Since lots of stuff gets omitted, perhaps you don't always see the extra log info...?